# How would one display raw input to TX pin on a HM-10 BLE module as a graph on a web app?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, digital-communications, bluetooth-low-energy, hm-10

Basically I'm trying to feed in High low signals into the TX pin of a HM-10 BLE module and display it as a graph, similar to how an oscilloscope would, or possibly just have a threshold where it would change some indicator on a web app. Chrome allows you to use bluetooth if you type in

chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

to the search bar and enable it, and applications exist to connect to them such as

https://loginov-rocks.github.io/Web-Bluetooth-Terminal/

https://github.com/ErniW/Web-Bluetooth-and-HM-10-module-for-Arduino

but they seem to be more focused on sending messages rather than raw 1 and 0 voltage input.

So.. How would one go about just receiving the data?

Thank you for your time and help if you can share some wisdom.

Comment: `but they seem to be more focused on sending messages rather than raw 1 and 0 voltage input` ... but you don't send voltage levels by Bluetooth... you send bytes

Comment: Well, maybe. I was able to just feed in raw voltage to a kcx_bt_emitter have it connect to a bluetooth speaker, and have it output noise if voltage is high/low. So it seems like it would be possible to just send the high low signals.

Comment: Bluetooth is a digital connection, not analog ... the data is a multiple of bytes

Comment: Seems like the best option would be to slap a micro controller in the middle and have it turn high low to transmittable data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically I want to be able to have a SPST NO switch that when closed will transmit a 1 to a web app and when open will transmit a 0 to a web app. From this also creating a graph of when the button was opened and when it was closed